# как проверить существует ли файл по url?

Tags: php

как можна с помощю php проверить существует ли файл по url 
например:
если файл http://minionomaniya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD.jpg
если да то делаем одно 
если нет то другое

Answer (score 0):

Взято с [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684771/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-from-a-url)

```
function is_url_exist($url){
    $ch = curl_init($url);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if($code == 200){
       $status = true;
    }else{
      $status = false;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
   return $status;
}
```